# How can different apps in SalesForce communicate with eachother? API? REST?

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, administration, isv

We have a customer which installed our app and another company's app. Both apps are (ISV) SalesForce apps.

The customer asked that we will do some integration between our apps, and I wonder what is the best way to do so?

Eventually the other app should be allowed to access some of our custom objects and be aware of our data. We will also need to update them on special occasions.

I wonder, is the other app can simply access our custom objects via SOQL queries? (using the fully qualified package name of our app)

Is there a better way? REST? or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another app can (as long as they haven't set limited [dynamic apex api](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=editing_client_security_profile.htm&language=en_US)) absolutely use your custom objects from SOQL/DML.

They may want to avoid hardcoding a dependency on your package by using the type names outright, but dynamic apex can solve that.